# What is the difference between HashMap<Long, String> and HashMap<>?

Tags: java, collections

What is the difference between

```
Map map = new HashMap<Long, String>();
```

and

```
Map map = new HashMap<>();
```

Which is better for use and why?

Comment: you might want to read up on generics : https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/index.html

Comment: Have you read the documentation ? Understand what a [Map](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html) and a [HashMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html) are

Comment: In your example, `Long` would be the type for the key and `String` would be the type of the value. You can't have a HashMap with no generic types.

Comment: @MC10 of course you can. It's called a raw type and should be avoided at all costs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The specification `HashMap<Long, String>()` is simply for the parameter types. But both the use cases you have shown are bad (I would just call it wrong) because the `map` object has no parameter types. What you should be doing is

```
Map<Long, String> map = new HashMap<Long, String>();
```

which is identical to

```
Map<Long, String> map = new HashMap<>();
```

The only difference between the two lines is whether you want to rely on automatic type inference of the JDK.

**Addendum:**

1. As Boris confirmed, in pre-JDK7, the automatic type inference was not possible, and the second way of initializing the map would not have compiled.
2. If you are using an IDE (really hope you are), please pay attention to warning about raw use of parametrized types.

Comment: And that the latter will not compile pre Java 7.

Comment: +. I wasn't sure about pre-JKD7, and was just googling to confirm that!

Answer (score 0):

Really it should be `Map<Long, String> map = new HashMap<>();` The 2 fields in the `<>` represent the key and value type of the map. So in this example it's a map of Strings which a referenced by Long values. Including them in the declaration forces the Map to ensure that the map can only have specific Key/Value types. It used to be that the types had to be included in the `<>` of the assignment but it hasn't been needed since Java 7.